# Race condition with multiple threads and mutex locks

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
int iGlobe = 0;
...
void thread1Func()
{
  Lock(&Mutex1);
  if(iGlobe == 0)         //step-1
    someaction();
}
...
void thread2Func()
{
  Lock(&Mutex2);
  iGlobe = 5;             //step-2
}
```

Suppose,

1) Thread1 executes step-1 and goes to sleep

2) Meanwhile Thread2 executes step-2 and changes value of iGlobe

How to overcome this situation?

Comment: Are you sure that there are 2 different `Mutex` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes they are two different mutexes...

Comment: You should have one mutex per resource that needs to be locked, and that mutex should be the same between all threads.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. One more sub-question. Can thread go to sleep in between executing instructions while mutex is locked?

Comment: @DivyangPatel It is possible but should be avoided. Keeping a mutex locked will block other threads that try to lock that same mutex. As a general rule try to keep a lock as short as possible to minimize time wasted waiting on mutexes.

Answer (score 5):

All accesses to a given piece of data have to synchronize on the same mutex, otherwise there is no "mutual exclusion" effect.  So, to fix your code, change thread2Func to say `Lock(&Mutex1)`.